# WPF: multiple foreground colors in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

In XAML we can set specific properties for each item in a `ComboBox`, for example:

```
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="Blue" Background="AntiqueWhite" Content="First Item"/>
<ComboBoxItem Foreground="Yellow" Background="Red" Content="Second Item"/>
```

When I try to do this when I'm dynamically filling a `ComboBox` from code, the `ComboBox .Foreground` property sets a foreground value on all the items. I would like to know if there's anyway to achieve this (setting different foreground colors for different items) in the code.

For example:

```
ComboBox1[First Item].Foreground = Brushes.Red;
ComboBox1[Second Item].Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

Comment: I'm not near a PC, do you know exactly what are the options? Maybe an `if` statement can help you. Like: `if (comboBox1.Content == "First Item") { comboBox1.Foreground = Brushes.Red}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to cast ComboBox's Item to `ComboBoxItem` type, then set it's `Foreground` property instead of the whole ComboBox's `Foreground` :

```
((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox1.Items[0]).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

**UPDATE :**

if you add new item to `ComboBox1` from code this way :

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem {Content = "Third Item"});
```

casting will work fine, because the code above resemble it's XAML counterpart you showed in question. But if you did it this way instead :

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Third Item");
```

casting won't work. Because that code added string to ComboBox Item instead of ComboBoxItem object. In this case getting ComboBoxItem is not as straightforward, you'll need to get it using `ItemContainerGenerator` as follow :

```
var comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)ComboBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ComboBox1.Items[0]);
comboBoxItem.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
```

Comment: Nice one! Casts are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="TestComboBox"
              Width="100"
              Height="30"
              Loaded="TestComboBox_Loaded">

        <ComboBoxItem Content="First Item"/>            
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Second Item"/>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void TestComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    if (comboBox != null) 
    {
        var firstItem = comboBox.Items[0] as ComboBoxItem;
        var secondItem = comboBox.Items[1] as ComboBoxItem;

        if (firstItem != null && secondItem != null)  
        {
            firstItem.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            secondItem.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```